# Custom Regex to filter out ID in the last urlpath

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have two types of url path name

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlQEoJaLQRA

https://www.youtube.com/sPfJQmpg5z
```

that as you can see, one has `watch?v=` prepended

My current parser in node.js `url.parse(mydata.imageurl).pathname` will only get the first word of the last url path but I need to implement regular expression so it will filter out the video ID (RlQEoJaLQRA and sPfJQmpg5z) in both of these case.

Can I get some help on implementing it with this custom regex?

**UPDATE**

I've tried the regex that was given by one of the answer in my code structure but the result is a bit off. I guess it's because of the way mine is referencing in chain like this? `data.list[item].given_url.match(regexp)`

```
    var video = [];
    var regexp = /[watch\]?[v=]?(\w+)$/i;

    Object.keys(data.list).forEach(function(item) {
        video.push({
            title : data.list[item].resolved_title,
            videoID : data.list[item].given_url.match(regexp)
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated regexp**

```
var a = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlQEoJaLQRA';
var b = 'https://www.youtube.com/sPfJQmpg5z';
var c = 'https://youtu.be/U-hzefHdAMk';
var getVideoId = function(src) {
  var regexp = /[watch\/v=]?([\w|\-]+)$/i;
  return src.match(regexp)[1];
};
```

`getVideoId(a);` outputs "RlQEoJaLQRA", `getVideoId(b);` outputs "sPfJQmpg5z" and `getVideo(c);` outputs "U-hzefHdAMk".

Comment: I'm trying to implement your regex in my structure

`var video = [];
  var regexp = /[watch\]?[v=]?(\w+)$/i;

  Object.keys(data.list).forEach(function(item) {
      video.push({
          title : data.list[item].resolved_title,
          videoID : data.list[item].given_url.match(regexp)
      })
  })` but I get the following result `{ title: 'Design Thinking - Tim Brown, CEO and President of IDEO',
    videoID: 
     [ 'hzefHdAMk',
       'zefHdAMk',
       index: 19,
       input: 'https://youtu.be/U-hzefHdAMk' ] } ]`

Comment: I updated the regexp, please see the answer. You need to grab `data.list[item].given_url.match(regexp)[1]` (notice [1] ref at the end).

Comment: Everything filtered fine except this one that original URL contains ID of `WAuDCOl9qrk` and it filtered as `AuDCOl9qrk`

Comment: could you post the full URL of that `WAuDC0l9qrk` since if I try it with defined URL's above, it seems to work.

Comment: Last update and now it works: `/[watch\/v=]?([\w|\-]+)$/i;`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var regexpr = /^https?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/(watch\?v=)?(.*)$/i;

var re1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlQEoJaLQRA'.match(regexpr)
console.log(re1[2]); // RlQEoJaLQRA

var re2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/sPfJQmpg5z'.match(regexpr);
console.log(re2[2]); // sPfJQmpg5z
```